# How to fix Vlookup in Google Sheet offset 1 cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a given data columns A,B,C & E. And I tried to write a vlookup formula with autofill function in cell F1 & G1. But I don't know why F2 & G2 are blanks and move all the results offset 1 cell.

F1 formula:

```
={ "EventStartDate"; arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(E:E,A$2:B,2,False))) }
```

G2 formula:

```
={ "BoothNo"; arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(E:E,A2:C,3,False))) }
```

[image]

Any thoughts to rewrite the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing E:E to E2:E

```
={ "EventStartDate"; arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(E2:E,A2:B,2,False))) }
```

and see if that works?